# Color for geometry selection?

Tags: selection, 3d

For a graphics application which selects vertices/edges & polygons, the color for highlighting selection needs to be easily identified.

Unlike typical text-selection it's overlaying solid geometry which has it's own shading. There are sometimes cases where selection is harder to see.

When testing colors I found some stand out more than others, although some people who tested this didn't find this to be the case. *See image below.*

Is there a deterministic rule for humans color perception which can help guide this choice or is this arbitrary?

[image: color comparison for geometry selection]

In this example the colored geometry is selected.

Comment: Maybe [ensuring that the contrast ratio is high enough](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) would be a good start?

Comment: Some colors catch the eyes more easily as compared to others. Warm colors will always reflect a little more light than cool colors but cyan (which is a cool color) would be more distinct to the human eyes as compared to the colors in the screenshot. Contrast and saturation play a huge role

Comment: @shreyas-tripathy that's my intuition too, is there color theory that backs this up? *(looking online, can only find peoples opinions and advice on the topic)*

Comment: @uwe-keim while contrast is important, it's not overlaying a single color, making it difficult to ensure contrast.

Comment: Use [this website](https://contrastchecker.com/) to make sure that the contrast ratio is high. That should help

Answer (score 2):

There's not any rule, in fact most graphic application allow users to set their own color for selected objects at the preferences or layer set up.

You can try other alternatives like blinking the selection while the object is selected but inactive using two opposite/complementary colors like cyan and red:

[image]

Comment: re: *There's not any rule, in fact most graphic application allow users to set their own color for selected objects at the preferences or layer set up.* - Just because something is configurable doesn't avoid the issue. It's important for a color scheme to have good default values.